# Layered graph with variable number of nodes on each layer

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I have created some TikZ code to produce the diagram below (slightly simplified).
This is my first real shot at TikZ and its taken me about 8 hours now to get this far.
But I don't really begrudge the time, time spent learning is time well spent.

It is loosely based on [this TeXample of a neural network (multilayer perceptron)](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/).

I would like to have a different (variable) number of nodes in each layer,
and would like to maintain the connection.

My current idea was to have a list of lists like `{{1..3},{1..5},{1..7},{1..4},{1..3}}`
then I guesss i could use a nested `for-each` off the index.
But that has 2 problems: I would lose my layer number, which I could get around by using `count`.
Secondly, more majorly, I don't seen a good way of knowing how big the next layer is (to make the connections).

[image: Neural Net]

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}


\def\layersep{3.5cm}
\def\topnum{5}
%\font\nullfont=cmr10
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,draw,fill=white!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{bias neuron}=[neuron,dashed]


    \foreach \y in {2,...,4}        
        \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
            \path   node[neuron] (L_\y_\x) at (\x cm,\y*\layersep) {$\sigma(\cdot)$};


% 
    \foreach  \x in {1,...,5}
            \path  node[neuron] (L_1_\x) at (\x cm,1*\layersep) {$x_\x$};

    \foreach  \x in {1,...,5}
            \path  node[neuron] (L_5_\x) at (\x cm,5*\layersep) {$s_{m}(\cdot)$};


    %Add Biases
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
    {
        \path node[bias neuron] (B_\y) at (6 cm, 0.55*\layersep+\y*\layersep) {1};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nextlayer{\y+1}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
            \path (B_\y) edge[dashed] (L_\nextlayer_\dest.south);
    }


    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \layer in {1,...,4}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nextlayer{\layer+1}
        \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
                \path (L_\layer_\source) edge (L_\nextlayer_\dest);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to add the list of lists for your `\sigma`-layers only or also for the top and bottom layers?

Comment: @moospit, doesn't matter. Ideally I would be able to handle all the layers the same. But I am already special casing the top and bottom, so it doens't matter - so long as everything ends up connected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s what I came up with after playing with the new graph syntax in PGF/TikZ 3 for a bit. I’m not sure if this was what you were looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,graphdrawing,arrows}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\sm{$s_{m}(\cdot)$}
\newcommand\sig{$\sigma(\cdot)$}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{>=latex',
    neuron/.style={circle,draw,fill=white!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt},
    bias neuron/.style={neuron,dashed}
}
\graph [allow inside edges=false, edges behind nodes] {
    // [
        layered layout, grow=up,        sibling sep=1em, level distance=6em,
        typeset=\sig,   nodes={neuron}
    ] { %tail anchor=north, head anchor=south]
    subgraph I_n [name=x, n=3, typeset=$x_\tikzgraphnodetext$] ->[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=B, n=5] ->[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=C, n=7] ->[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=D, n=4] ->[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=E, n=3, typeset=\sm]
    },
    {[typeset=1, nodes={bias neuron}, edges={dashed}]
    Bone [x=8em,y=18em]  -> subgraph I_n [name=B, n=5],
    Cone [x=8em,y=26.5em]-> subgraph I_n [name=C, n=7],
    Done [x=8em,y=36em]  -> subgraph I_n [name=D, n=4],
    Eone [x=8em,y=43.5em]-> subgraph I_n [name=E, n=3]
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously this can be improved in many ways (*x<sub>i</sub>* nodes in reverse order, repeated *I<sub>n</sub>* node groups, manual placement of bias neuron nodes, dotted lines overlapping neuron nodes).

Disclaimer: I’ve only recently started getting to know the cool new parts of PGF/TikZ 3 since upgrading it yesterday. However, I did want to show how to take advantage of the new graph syntax to avoid writing out for loops and calculating node positions.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am looking for. Man, so much nicer. Could have save alot of effort, (but missed out on alot of learning))
Where is the documentation for TikZ3?

Comment: It should come with your TeX distribution; run `texdoc pgf`. Otherwise, see the CTAN-hosted [PGF/TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). Read chapter 19 and part IV for graph-related fun.

Comment: I don't like the manual positioning of the bias (one) nodes, and am trying to work out away to not have to do that. Any idea's? How did you come up with the manual positions?

Comment: I would have expected all the bias (one) nodes to be verially seperated from each other by the smae amount (6 em which is the leval difference), but they are separated by Seemingly random amounts as the graph layout takes the  level distance as a suggestion (from the look of things)