# Draw a radial basis function diagram in LyX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the following simple radial basis function diagram in my LyX document:

[image: example]

So, I need help to write the LaTeX code, but I would like the output image to be as follows:

[image: wanted]

I tried this code in ERT box of Lyx which gave me Figure number 2 .. but I am clueless that how include the special symbol inside the circle node of hidden layer.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=8.5pt
    },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Input\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
& & \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\
};
\foreach \ai [count=\mi ]in {2,4,...,10}
     \draw[<-] (mat-\ai-1) -- node[above] {I\mi} +(-1cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {2,4,...,10}
{\foreach \aii in {3,6,9}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}
\foreach \ai in {3,6,9}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-6-3);
\draw[->] (mat-6-3) -- node[above] {O1} +(1cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to the website. You should post some relevant code and show that you have made an effort to draw it yourself.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Added Code Which I found online, but I am confused to  insert the special character symbol in the circle part. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Somewhat similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171770/layered-graph-with-variable-number-of-nodes-on-each-layer/171799#171799

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this be it?

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper size={15cm,15cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=8.5pt
    },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Input\\layer} & 
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer} &
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]| $\vdots$\\
|[plain]|$\vdots$& & \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]|$\vdots$ \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\
};
\foreach \ai [count=\mi ]in {2,4}
     \draw[<-] (mat-\ai-1) -- node[above] {$x_\mi$} +(-1cm,0);
     \draw[<-] (mat-8-1) -- node[above] {$x_{p-1}$} +(-1cm,0);
     \draw[<-] (mat-10-1) -- node[above] {$x_{p}$} +(-1cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {2,4,8,10}
{\foreach \aii in {3,6,9}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2)node(){$\varphi$};
}
  \draw[->] (mat-3-2) --node[above]{$w_1$} (mat-6-3);
  \draw[->] (mat-6-2) --node[above]{$w_j$} (mat-6-3);
  \draw[->] (mat-9-2) --node[above]{$w_N$} (mat-6-3);
\draw[->] (mat-6-3) -- node[above] {$F(x)$} +(2cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```