# Draw a RBF model in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I am just learning LaTeX recently to write a report. So I am unfamiliar with most LaTeX commands and environments. Can someone help me? 
I am trying to draw the following model in LaTeX.

[image]

Edit: After the help from N3buchadnezzar, I tried to make some changes as needed, but the problem now is the spacing between arrows and their labels. The best result is as shown, I want to make it as close to the first image as possible. Help!
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,matrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=10pt
    },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net,row sep=0em, column sep=4em] (mat)
{
|[plain]|& |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering $C_j , \sigma_j$} &|[plain]|\\
             &           \\
  |[plain]|  & |[plain]| &  &  &        \\
             &      &  |[plain]|$\vdots$  \\
  |[plain]|$\vdots$ & |[plain]|$\vdots$ &  &  &      \\
             &           \\
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering I}& |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering J} &|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering K}\\
};
\foreach \ai in {2,4,6}
  {\foreach \aii in {2,4,6}
    \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}

  \draw[->] (mat-2-2) --node[above]{$w_{11}$} (mat-3-3)node(){$\sum$};
  \draw[->] (mat-2-2) --node[above]{$w_{21}$} (mat-5-3)node(){$\sum$};
  \draw[->] (mat-4-2) --node[below]{$w_{12}$} (mat-3-3);
  \draw[->] (mat-4-2) --node[below]{$w_{22}$} (mat-5-3);
  \draw[->] (mat-6-2) --node[above]{$w_{1j}$} (mat-3-3);
  \draw[->] (mat-6-2) --node[below]{$w_{kj}$} (mat-5-3);

\draw[->] (mat-3-3)  --node[above]{$y_1$} (mat-3-4); 
\draw[->] (mat-3-5)node(){$t_i$} -- (mat-3-4);

\draw[->] (mat-5-3) --node[above]{$y_k$} (mat-5-4); 
\draw[->] (mat-5-5)node(){$t_k$} -- (mat-5-4);


\node(x1)  at (mat-2-1){$x_1$}; 
\node(s1) at (mat-2-2)[label=below:$(C_{11}...C_{1i})$]{$\sigma_1$};
\node(x1) at (mat-4-1){$x_2$}; 
\node(s2) at (mat-4-2)[label=below:$(C_{21}...C_{2i})$]{$\sigma_2$};
\node(x1) at (mat-6-1){$x_i$}; 
\node(s3) at (mat-6-2)[label=below:$(C_{j1}...C_{ji})$]{$\sigma_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point. See how far you can get on your own. I simply used ideas from [Draw a radial basis function diagram in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174435/draw-a-radial-basis-function-diagram-in-lyx).

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper size={15cm,15cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=8.5pt
    },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net,row sep=0em, column sep=3em] (mat)
{
             &           \\
  |[plain]|  & |[plain]| &  &  &        \\
             &           \\
  |[plain]|$\vdots$ & |[plain]|$\vdots$ &  &  &      \\
             &           \\
};
\foreach \ai in {1,3,5}
  {\foreach \aii in {1,3,5}
    \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}
\foreach \ai in {1,3,5}
  {\foreach \aii in {2,4}
    \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\aii-3)node(){$\sum$};
}
\draw[->] (mat-2-3) -- (mat-2-4); \draw[->] (mat-2-5)node(){$t_i$} -- (mat-2-4);
 
\draw[->] (mat-4-3) -- (mat-4-4); \draw[->] (mat-4-5)node(){$t_k$} -- (mat-4-4);

\node(x1) at (mat-1-1){$x_1$}; \node(s1) at (mat-1-2){$\sigma_1$};
\node(x1) at (mat-3-1){$x_2$}; \node(s2) at (mat-3-2){$\sigma_2$};
\node(x1) at (mat-5-1){$x_i$}; \node(s3) at (mat-5-2){$\sigma_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```